# How to change Wicket behaviour on Page Expired

Tags: wicket

We have a wicket application for our main website. Lately we have implemented a mobile version of the site. The mobile version is special in that it is deployed inside a native app wrapper to some mobile devices and not connected to the rest of the page through links because it is not supposed to be normally visible to web users.

The mobile page makes use of ajax and is therefore prone to receive "Page expired" errors for example when we restart the application on the server.

Since that page is not connected to the rest of the application through links I do not want our standard "Page expired" behaviour. Is it possible to override or intercept this behaviour for the pages belonging to the mobile part of the site? For example I could like to be able to configure the pages to simply reload on a "Page expired" error.

Comment: A simple reload would not be possible to my knowledge, as the Page (with its state) is stored in the session. And the Page expired message occours when the session has been discarded from the servlet container, hence the state is lost.

Comment: You are right that the state is lost. I don't want to restore the state just a reload of the url would suffice. The exceptions come from using Ajax on the page. The page itself doesn't store state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,

```
getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(YourPage.class)
```

YourPage.class can then for instance be your HomePage or another Page that depending on it being a request from a mobile device does something else.

If you would like to reload the Page the user was one then it becomes a bit less trivial. Reloading the Page is not possible since you are not on the page anymore. You could have a look at `IRequestCycleListener` and overriding `onException` and handle PageExpiredException yourself but it is a dangerous road you travel if you simply reload your Page. Navigating to the home (or other) page seems more logical. I assume you are not restarting your server 100 times per day...

Comment: We are already setting that PageExpiredErrorPage for the application. I would like different behaviour for the mobile version. In the future we will probably need two wicket applications. I like the other idea with the RequestCycleListener.

Comment: How can I pass a `PageParameter` in this way?

Comment: I don't think it is possible via IApplicationSettings