# How to use a different Wicket expiration/error page for popups and other special pages?

Tags: error-handling, wicket

I have a custom error and expiration page in my wicket application. But in some cases, I would like to have them behave differently (e.g. in a popup that should NOT redirect us to home page).

What are the options for the solution? I assume I can read the page parameters in my error/expiration page from the request object (e.g. "errorpage=no"). But how can I add this query parameter to specific pages in optimal way..?

I'm quite certain someone has solved this already so this would be a great opportunity to share a nice solution here..

Relatively similar question:
[How to change Wicket behaviour on Page Expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393902/how-to-change-wicket-behaviour-on-page-expired)

Comment: Actually the trickiest part is to call the specific pages with URL and/or parameters that can be detected in the RequestCycleListener or error page implementation.

One of the easiest way is to use mount("popup",PopupPage.class). This does not work for inherited pages, but that can be solved too with more compilicated **MountedMapper**.

Answer (score 3):

You could just register a RequestCycleListener that listens "onException" and handles exceptions differently depending on the RequestCycle and otherwise fallback to the default implementation.

(Code based on Wicket 6.6)

```
        getRequestCycleListeners().add(new AbstractRequestCycleListener() {
        @Override
        public IRequestHandler onException(RequestCycle cycle, Exception ex) {
            if (ex instanceof PageExpiredException) {
                //handle your pageExpiredException...

                if (something) {
                    return new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(HomePage.class));
                }

            }

            return super.onException(cycle, ex);
        }
    });
```